# Two Sum Leetcode - Getting [0,0] on multiple lists input

Tags: python, list

I'm a beginner and trying to solve the two sum leetcode (easy problem).
I know my code is kind of basic but it works when I try it in another workspace(codecademy) and it also works if the leet code input is only 1 list.

However, when leetcode applies 2-3 lists(testcases on the site), the 2nd and 3rd list returns [0,0]. Anyone knows why it returns [0,0]?.
I think it's related to line 2 of the code, which was provided by leetcode at the start, related to `Class solution: def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:` because when I provide a different list in Codecademy, it works.

I also tried removing `break` since I thought that stops it from getting multiple inputs but it doesn't fix the issue.

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:

        lengthlist = len(nums)       
        a = 0
        b = 0
        
        for numbera in nums:
            for numberb in nums:
                if nums[a] + nums[b] == target:
                    if a < b:
                        return [a,b]
                        break
                    else:
                        return [b,a]
                        break
                else:
                    continue
                a += 1
            b += 1
```

EDIT / CONCLUSION:
Found the issue with the code based from the comments.

The leetcode problem specifies that I may not use the same element twice.
I did not account for this since I'm using `range(0, len(nums))` on both `for` loops. I realized my code only worked if I used i+1 when I copied AboAmar's reply at the start of the 2nd `for` loop.

The 2nd test case has [3,2,4] with 6 target. My code was returning [0,0] because 3+3 is 6. But leetcode outputs [1,2] because I can't use the same element twice in the list.

Comment: Those breaks are dead code, should be removed. They have no effect on your program whatsoever.

Comment: you iterate with `numbera` and `numberb` as variables, but then inside you use `a` and `b` instead. Do you mean to do `if numbera + numberb == target`. Then what are a and b supposed to do? some kind of indices? use `enumerate` if you need indices

Comment: "Anyone knows why it returns [0,0]" - 99% sure it's a bug in your code. Your loops look strange (you're not using `numbera` / `numberb`, for example). What is the value of that list, that makes this code return `[0, 0]`?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki: they need both indices and values, though. Compare values, but return indices. Can python's `for in` do that?

Comment: You don't need that `if a < b`, btw. From the description: "You can return the answer in any order."

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes, use enumerate like this: `for a, numbera in enumerate(nums)`

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I was now able to find the rootcause of the issue. I will comment the details on AboAmmar's reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straightforward loop, since the order is not important and only one solution is assumed.

```
def twoSum(self, nums, target):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(nums)):
            if nums[i] + nums[j] == target:
                return [i, j]
```

As you can see, you need both the index and the value. The index of the inner loop `j` takes from the next `i` to the end of the array. So, you don't need the comparisons `a < b`, etc. Also, `break` is not needed as you already `return` upon finding the solution.

Comment: Your comment helped me find the wrong thing with my code. Thanks. 

Here's the issue:
The leetcode problem specifies that I may not use the same element twice. I did not account for this.

I realized my code only worked if I used i+1 at the start of the 2nd `for loop`.

The 2nd test case has [3,2,4] with 6 target. My code was returning [0,0] because 3+3 is 6.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Solution {
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    int first=-1,second=-1;
    boolean flag=false;

    for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<nums.length; j++)
        {
            if(i!=j)
            {
                if(nums[i]+nums[j]==target)
                {
                    first=i;
                    second=j;
                    flag=true;
                }
            }
        }
        if(flag==true)
            break;
    }
    int[] arr= new int[2];
    arr[0]=first;
    arr[1]=second;

    return(arr);
}
}
```

Comment: Since you know that there will be only 2 indices that have to be returned so you can create an array of size 2 and individually assign the two indices to each of the indexes of the resultant array.